# Countdown in Javafx with maximize

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently trying to develop a countdown which contains 3 values.

The first value how long the countdown should run, the 2nd value is from when the countdown turns orange and the 3rd from when the countdown turns red.
I have a problem with my countdown that spins around now and then, sometimes runs faster, when I resume the countdown it starts spinning!
I have a question, if I want to maximize the application, I want it to automatically enlarge all the objects in the scene.
the User interface was built with Scene Builder.
Thanks for your help.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception   {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/Countdown.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/gui/application.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
package application.controller.gui;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CountDownController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane menuPane;

    @FXML
    private Text timerText;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton resertButton;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton pauseButton;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane timerPane;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> schwellWertStunden1;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> schwellWertMinuten1;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> schwellWertStunden2;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> schwellWertMinuten2;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> startStunden;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> startMinuten;

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<Integer> startSekunden;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton startButton;

    Map<Integer, String> numberMap;
    Integer currSeconds;
    Thread thrd;;

    @FXML
    void start(ActionEvent event) {
        startCountDown();
        Combo();
    }

    void startCountDown() {
        thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LocalTime localTimeCounter = LocalTime.of(startStunden.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),
                            startMinuten.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),
                            startSekunden.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

                    LocalTime localTimeSchwellwert1 = LocalTime.of(schwellWertStunden1.getValue(),
                            schwellWertMinuten1.getValue());
                    LocalTime localTimeSchwellwert2 = LocalTime.of(schwellWertStunden2.getValue(),
                            schwellWertMinuten2.getValue());

                    boolean bSchwellert1Erreicht = false;

                    while (true) {
                        localTimeCounter = localTimeCounter.minusSeconds(1);

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        timerText.setText(localTimeCounter.toString());

                        if (localTimeCounter.isBefore(localTimeSchwellwert1) && !bSchwellert1Erreicht) {
                            timerText.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

                            bSchwellert1Erreicht = true;
                        }

                        if (localTimeCounter.isBefore(localTimeSchwellwert2)) {
                            timerText.setFill(Color.RED);
                        }

                        if (localTimeCounter.toSecondOfDay() <= 0) {
                            thrd.stop();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });
        thrd.start();
    }

    @FXML
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void pauseAction(ActionEvent event) {
        thrd.stop();
    }

    void siZe() {

    }

    void Combo() {
        if (schwellWertMinuten1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() <= schwellWertMinuten2.getSelectionModel()
                .getSelectedIndex()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Bitte überprüfen sie denn Schwellwert 2!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Der Schwellwert 2 darf nicht kleiner oder gleich Schwellwert 1 sein!");
            alert.setContentText("");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @FXML
    void resetAction(ActionEvent event1) {
        thrd.stop();
        timerText.setText("00:00:00");
        timerText.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<Integer> stundenListe = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Integer> minutenSekunden = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
            if (0 <= i && i <= 24) {
                stundenListe.add(new Integer(i));
            }
            minutenSekunden.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        startStunden.setItems(stundenListe);
        startStunden.setValue(0);
        schwellWertStunden1.setItems(stundenListe);
        schwellWertStunden1.setValue(0);
        schwellWertStunden2.setItems(stundenListe);
        schwellWertStunden2.setValue(0);

        startMinuten.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        startMinuten.setValue(0);

        schwellWertMinuten1.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        schwellWertMinuten2.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        schwellWertMinuten1.setValue(0);
        schwellWertMinuten2.setValue(0);
        startSekunden.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        startSekunden.setValue(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<JFXTabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller.gui.CountDownController">
    <tabs>
        <Tab closable="false" text="Countdown">
            <content>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: white">
                    <children>
                        <Text fx:id="timerText" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="00:00:00 " textOrigin="CENTER" wrappingWidth="398.00001430511475">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="96.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="pauseButton" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" onAction="#pauseAction" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="91.0" fitWidth="109.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../2000px-Gnome-media-playback-pause.svg.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </JFXButton>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="resertButton" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" onAction="#resetAction" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="65.0" fitWidth="109.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../icon-1294478_960_720.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </JFXButton>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Werte">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="timerPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="951.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
                    <children>
                        <Text layoutX="170.0" layoutY="110.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Startwert:" wrappingWidth="127.21630859375">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text fill="#ffcd05" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="160.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="  Schwellwert 1:" wrappingWidth="198.41015625">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text fill="#e40505" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="210.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="  Schwellwert 2:">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="startStunden" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="startMinuten" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="startSekunden" disable="true" labelFloat="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" promptText=" sek" visible="false" />
                        <JFXButton fx:id="startButton" layoutX="249.0" layoutY="262.0" onAction="#start" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Start">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
                            </padding>
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../play-97626_1280.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </JFXButton>
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="schwellWertStunden1" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="schwellWertMinuten1" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="131.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="schwellWertStunden2" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <JFXComboBox fx:id="schwellWertMinuten2" labelFloat="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="181.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</JFXTabPane>
```

Comment: Can you show your .FXML?

Comment: yes, I have uploaded my .FXML

Comment: [mcve] please - strip it down to the barest minimum demonstrating the problem, nothing unrelated. That said: you __must not__ change properties of a node in an active scenegraph off the javafx application thread!

Comment: Use something from JavaFX's Animation API if you can.

Answer (score 0):

To change the properties of nodes in a `JavaFx` based gui use a `JavaFx` animation tool.
The following [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mre) uses a [PauseTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) instance for the job. 
To make the code independent on `JFoenix` I used `JavaFx` components:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CountDownController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane menuPane;

    @FXML
    private Text timerText;

    @FXML
    private Button resertButton, pauseButton, startButton;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane timerPane;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer> schwellWertStunden1, schwellWertMinuten1, schwellWertStunden2, schwellWertMinuten2;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer> startStunden, startMinuten, startSekunden;

    private LocalTime localTimeCounter;
    private boolean bSchwellert1Erreicht;
    private PauseTransition pauseTransition;

    @FXML
    void start(ActionEvent event) {
        startCountDown();
        Combo();
    }

    void startCountDown() {

        try {
            localTimeCounter = LocalTime.of(startStunden.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),
                    startMinuten.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(),
                    startSekunden.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

            LocalTime localTimeSchwellwert1 = LocalTime.of(schwellWertStunden1.getValue(),
                    schwellWertMinuten1.getValue());
            LocalTime localTimeSchwellwert2 = LocalTime.of(schwellWertStunden2.getValue(),
                    schwellWertMinuten2.getValue());

            bSchwellert1Erreicht = false;

            pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(.21));
            pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event ->{

                localTimeCounter = localTimeCounter.minusSeconds(1);
                timerText.setText(localTimeCounter.toString());

                if (localTimeCounter.isBefore(localTimeSchwellwert1) && !bSchwellert1Erreicht) {
                    timerText.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
                    bSchwellert1Erreicht = true;
                }

                if (localTimeCounter.isBefore(localTimeSchwellwert2)) {
                    timerText.setFill(Color.RED);
                }

                if (localTimeCounter.toSecondOfDay() <= 0) {
                    pauseTransition.stop();
                    return;
                }
                pauseTransition.play();
            });
            pauseTransition.play();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void pauseAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if(pauseTransition != null) {
            pauseTransition.stop();
        }
    }

    void siZe() {}

    void Combo() {
        if (schwellWertMinuten1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() <= schwellWertMinuten2.getSelectionModel()
                .getSelectedIndex()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Bitte überprüfen sie denn Schwellwert 2!");
            alert.setHeaderText("Der Schwellwert 2 darf nicht kleiner oder gleich Schwellwert 1 sein!");
            alert.setContentText("");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void resetAction(ActionEvent event1) {
        if(pauseTransition != null) {
            pauseTransition.stop();
        }
        timerText.setText("00:00:00");
        timerText.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<Integer> stundenListe = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Integer> minutenSekunden = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
            if (0 <= i && i <= 24) {
                stundenListe.add(i);
            }
            minutenSekunden.add(i);
        }
        startStunden.setItems(stundenListe);
        startStunden.setValue(0);
        schwellWertStunden1.setItems(stundenListe);
        schwellWertStunden1.setValue(0);
        schwellWertStunden2.setItems(stundenListe);
        schwellWertStunden2.setValue(0);
        startMinuten.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        startMinuten.setValue(0);

        schwellWertMinuten1.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        schwellWertMinuten2.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        schwellWertMinuten1.setValue(0);
        schwellWertMinuten2.setValue(0);
        startSekunden.setItems(minutenSekunden);
        startSekunden.setValue(0);
    }
}
```

Countdown.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.CountDownController">
    <tabs>
        <Tab closable="false" text="Countdown">
            <content>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: white">
                    <children>
                        <Text fx:id="timerText" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="00:00:00 " textOrigin="CENTER" wrappingWidth="398.00001430511475">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="96.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Button fx:id="pauseButton" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" onAction="#pauseAction" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="91.0" fitWidth="109.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../2000px-Gnome-media-playback-pause.svg.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="resertButton" alignment="TOP_RIGHT" onAction="#resetAction" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="65.0" fitWidth="109.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../icon-1294478_960_720.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Werte">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane fx:id="timerPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="951.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
                    <children>
                        <Text layoutX="170.0" layoutY="110.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Startwert:" wrappingWidth="127.21630859375">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text fill="#ffcd05" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="160.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="  Schwellwert 1:" wrappingWidth="198.41015625">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text fill="#e40505" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="210.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="  Schwellwert 2:">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="29.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="startStunden"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="startMinuten"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="startSekunden" disable="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" promptText=" sek" visible="false" />
                        <Button fx:id="startButton" layoutX="249.0" layoutY="262.0" onAction="#start" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Start">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
                            </padding>
                            <graphic>
                                <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                    <image>
                                        <Image url="@../../../../../play-97626_1280.png" />
                                    </image>
                                </ImageView>
                            </graphic>
                        </Button>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="schwellWertStunden1"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="130.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="schwellWertMinuten1"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="131.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="schwellWertStunden2"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  std" visible="false" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="schwellWertMinuten2"  layoutX="350.0" layoutY="181.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="60.0" promptText="  min" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
</TabPane>
```